# How to politely refuse to answer questions about your planned travel?

Tags: expressions

I am going to have an on-site interview for two weekdays. I told my team leader that I am going to be on travel for two days. He asked, "Where are you going?"

I answered, "some personal business". Then both our smiles froze for about ten seconds.

Is my reply not appropriate? What could be a better response in this situation?

Comment: You can't really answer this question by learning more about English. You're basically asking "what's the best way to deal with this social situation?" Factors like your company's culture and your relationship with your team leader will affect this just as much as, or more than, linguistic factors. Maybe there was no type of refusal that would have made your team leader happy. Who can say?

Comment: @sumelic In terms of how to deal with the situation, I already determined not to answer the question. So as far as I can tell, it's still an English usage question of how to express that refusal correctly and optimally.

Comment: Saying it's "personal business" is as polite and honest as you can hope to be, plus saying "personal" serves to imply that further inquiry into the matter would not be inappropriate.  Of course, your team leader may suspect that you're going on a job interview, but you can't help that.  You could of course lie and say you're going to visit your sick elderly aunt, but lies like that have a tendency to snowball.

Comment: @HotLicks - I am so glad to hear my answer actually was not that...err... bad.

Comment: Oops, I said "would not be inappropriate".  One too many nots in there -- it *would* be inappropriate for your team leader to inquire very deeply into something you specify is "personal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response you gave is technically correct, of course. Without getting into the social aspects of the interaction, saying "some personal business" sounds a little cold and businesslike, maybe even unfriendly. A chit-chatty answer to a chit-chatty question (possibly including a minor lie) could have seemed warmer without revealing information you don't want to reveal:

- "I have a personal obligation to take care of."
- "I'm going to visit my family."

Something like that.

Comment: The first one sounds great. Not a lie in anyway, yet able to deflect the question nicely. +1